# Power Dissipation of Diode

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, diodes

I have two diode datasheets.

[Onsemi](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MRA4003T3-D.PDF)

[Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88711/s1.pdf)

In both the datasheets, why is the maximum allowable power dissipation of the diode not provided in the absolute maximum ratings table.

Usually, in electronic components, I have seen the absolute maximum ratings table which will include the maximum allowable power dissipation for transistors and other components. But why in these diode datasheets, the maximum power is missing?

Comment: It's the junction temperature that you have to limit, which has a dependency on \$R_{θJA}\$ and \$R_{θJL}\$ and the \$R_θ\$ lead-to-PCB and PCB-to-ambient. I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *But why in these diode datasheets, the maximum power is missing?*

The maximum power dissipation is directly related to the maximum forward current and the forward conduction voltage (also pretty much related to forward current) so that is what is specified. Work with forward current and, if you need to know the power multiply the forward power by (say) 0.7 volts to 1 volt.

I don't recall ever seeing maximum power stated in a diode data sheet. It's always current that is specified. You get maximum power stated in BJT and MOSFET data sheets because current and voltage are not at all so easily relatable. You also get a safe operating area (SOA) graph in BJT and MOSFET data sheets but never in a diode data sheet from what I can recall.

Answer (score 0):

If you could use a diode as a controlled resistor *(like MOSFETs and BJTs in, for example, linear regulators)* then the max allowed power dissipation would be a limiting parameter. As Andy has stated in his answer, forward current and also the max reverse voltage are the parameters you should consider.